# Do I need to sanitize user input when using Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

In the past, I was under the impression that sequelize somehow automatically prevented SQL injection, but the current version of the manual implies that there are situations where sanitization is required ([link](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators))

Sorry if this is a silly question, but I haven't been able to find any definite answer as to whether or not sanitization is required when using sequelize.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For general safety you should always try and sanitise any data coming from user input. However, using operators is much safer. Always use `Sequelize.Op` where possible

Comment: If I use operators, then what part of the input do I need to sanitize?

Comment: That is more a general question about sanitisation. The docs, and my comment, are just warning that there are problems, and there is no such thing as a perfect non-penetrable system. Using things like Sequelize.Op helps mitigate risk. For example, if you let someone type in a phrase to search by. Someone could type `%' UNION SELECT password FROM Users where username LIKE '%`. If you didnt sanitise that and it went to a raw query like `sequelize.query("SELECT x FROM y WHERE x like '%" + query + "%'",
      { type: models.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT}
    )` You may have issues

Answer (score 3):

Other than agreeing with McCabe's answer, I want to add that sequelize at least takes care of unescaped strings, which one could argue is a big part of handling SQL Injection issues. Even if you want to write custom queries, this is also possible using replacements, as stated in the first sentence [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/raw-queries.html#bind-parameter): "...**replacements are escaped** and inserted into the query by sequelize before the query is sent to the database...".